# How do i get the value inside a multiple type vector (without adding the <type>)?

Tags: c++

I created a vector that stores any type of value (int, bool, string, &, object,...). I can store stuff, but i have no idea how to get an specific element ([index]). EDIT: (without adding the type)

I haven't tried many things because i have no clue. The only tecnic i can think of is dynamic_cast, but since is a template makes no sense.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct slot {
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

template<typename kind>
struct item : public slot {
    kind value;
    item(kind value) : value{ value } {};
    void print()override { std::cout << value<<std::endl; }
};


class Bag {

    std::vector<slot*> backpack;

public:
    template<typename kind>
    void append(kind stuff) {
        backpack.push_back(new item<kind>(stuff));
    }
    void print_to_test() {
        for (slot* it : backpack) { it->print(); }
    }
    //kind get()...How do i get an item value?
};
```

```
Bag bag;
bag.append(1);
bag.append(true);
bag.append("Hola");
bag.append(1232131);
void* a = nullptr;
bag.append(a);
bag.print_to_test();
//works fine, prints everything
//but can't get an specific value, like bag[index]
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question so we wouldn't have to guess, what do you want to achieve, what did you achieved and what is failing.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` would work just fine. Can you share what you have tried with it that failed?

Comment: Can you use c++17? If yes, please consider using std::any or std::variant.

Comment: That's what std::any is for.

Comment: That is a problem. Try and go around it by not getting items out, but passing into the item an object that the unknown type can manipulate to perform whatever operation you need done.

Comment: *"but can't get an specific value, like bag[index]"* Are you trying to implement `operator[]` for your `Bag` class?

Comment: I have an incinerator, I can store stuff inside, but I have a problem retrieving anything... sorry that was a cheap shot. Technically these kitchen sink classes that store anything *usually* signify a problem in your design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dynamic cast will work. Note that it requires at least one virtual method - a destructor can be used if nothing else.
Yes, there isn't a way how can you reliably retrieve the value. C++ doesn't have a general `object` base as other languages nor any useful runtime reflection.
What you've implemented is known as type erasure and is actually used in e.g. `std::function` or `std::any`.

You should not use raw pointers and `new` for ownership. Use `std::unique_ptr` instead. Also since you only refer to the objects through the base class you need the virtual destructor. Otherwise, you won't be able to `delete` them correctly, again one more reason for `std::unique_ptr` as it deletes the pointer by itself.

If you want to get the value, what would you do with it? To quote Bjarne Stroustrup:

> There is no useful universal class: a truly universal carries no semantics of its own.

Yes, you can store this value in `std::any`, but that's it, what would you want to do with it? Print it? Well, in that case it's no longer `any` but `printable` as in your example, so either use templates or virtual methods to express these traits in the types of the stored objects.

Consider using `std::variant` for known set of possible types and prefer `std::any` to owning `void*`. If you need the latter rethink your design choices first.

Comment: It would be nice to comment that `std::shared_ptr` also implements type erasure, and can be used with `std::shared_ptr<void>`. In this case, because of this feature, it would be a useful replacement for `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, dynamic_cast will work fine (as long as the caller knows what type is in the specific index) :

```
item<int>& someInt = dynamic_cast<item<int>&>(*bag.backpack[0]);
std::cout << "someInt: ";
someInt.print();
```

Note: You didn't provide accessor to backpack member, so I assumed it's public

Output:

> someInt: 1